# How to control the interlinked comboBoxes output?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform

I have two `ComboBox`es in a `Userform`.

The first `Combox`- `ComboBox1` is updated with `Items` as soon as the `Userform` is initialized, as below.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ComboBox1
        .AddItem "A"
        .AddItem "B"
    End With
End Sub
```

Now once a value of the `ComboxBox1` is selected, it updates the second `ComboBox` - `ComboBox2`, as below -

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()    
    With ComboBox2
        .Clear
        .AddItem "P"
        .AddItem "Q"
        .AddItem "R"
    End With
End Sub
```

And the `ComboBox2` on change displays its current value -

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    MsgBox ComboBox2.Value
End Sub
```

Now when I select a value from `ComboBox1` for the first time, `ComboBox2` is updated and further on selecting a value from `CombBox2`, I get a popup message with the `ComboBox2` value --- **This is fine**.

Now again I select a different value from `ComboBox1`, this time I get a blank popup message, (because it cleared the `ComboBox2` content).

How can I handle this, as I don't want the `MsgBox` popup on changing the `ComboBox1`, I want the popup only on manually selecting values from `ComboBox2`?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because once ComboBox2 has a value and you change ComboBox1 (and `.clear` combobox2 - it changes ComboBox2. Just use this for combobox2 -

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
If ComboBox2.ListCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox ComboBox2.Value
End Sub
```